# How to add a tooltip to existing svg circles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have multiple existing SVG circles exported from CorelDraw and would like each to have unique text appear in a tooltip on hover.
Inside g element where are circles I added text elements. I located each text next to corresponding circle and with corresponding text.

```
<g id="cities" class="gradici">
<circle class="first" r="7" />
<circle class="second" r="7 />
</g>

var Citytooltip = svg.selectAll("g.gradici").selectAll("text")
                  .data(naziviGradova)
                  .enter()
                  .append("text")
                  .style("visibility", "hidden")
                  .attr("x", function(d,i){return graddx[i]})
                  .attr("y",function(d,i){return graddy[i]})
                  .text(function(d) {return d;})
                  .attr("font-size", "10px")
                  .attr("fill", "#black");
```

I menage to get when I hover over any circle that all text is visible/hidden next to all circles.

```
var city= svg.selectAll("#cities circle");

city
   .on("mouseover", (function(){Citytooltip.style("visibility", 
   "visible");}))
   .on("mouseout", (function(){Citytooltip.style("visibility", 
   "hidden");}));
```

But I am straggling how to get text to be visible/hidden just over the circle I am hovering. I suppose I should somehow iterate trough city but I am stuck how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I menage to solve my problem, so I will leave the answer if someone get stuck like me.

```
var titleCreate = svg.selectAll("g.gradici circle").append("title").text("tooltip");
for (var i =0; i<naziviGradova.length; i++){                                    
  var textNazivaGradova = naziviGradova[i];
  var title = svg.getElementsByTagName("title");
  title[i].innerHTML = textNazivaGradova;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add a `title`, `description` or `metadata` elements as content for a `circle` element in order for the user agent to provide tooltips (depending on the user agent):

```
<g id="cities" class="gradici">
    <desc>A group of circles</desc>
    <circle class="first" r="7">
        <desc>First circle</desc>
    </circle>
    <circle class="second" r="7>
        <desc>Second circle</desc>
    </circle>
</g>
```

This is [specified by SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermDescriptiveElement).

For modern desktop and mobile Web browsers, the provided element descriptions are typically rendered as you describe and expect -- as tooltips appearing when the user "hovers their pointer device" over the `circle` element that e.g. contains the `desc` element.

My advice would be to not reinvent the wheel with elaborate and complicated script-based solutions that always carry the risk of breaking for some of your users, not when something like the above is part of SVG already and suffices for you.

Comment: thank you for answer. I know I can add the title to every circle, but solving this problem with javascript would give me more possibilities if I want to add anything else except the text.

Comment: You can absolutely put other elements inside `desc`, so technically you *can* add anything, but these will not be rendered in the browsers I have tested -- Firefox and Chrome. Perhaps a hybrid solution would work best -- keep the tooltip content in a declarative fashion inside `desc` elements inside `circle`, but use JavaScript (e.g. `mouseenter`) and/or CSS to actually have them rendered. I'll write up another answer demonstrating this solution.

Comment: Thanks man, adding the <title> tag inside the circle worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If user agent tooltips aren't going to cut it, one will have to implement some of the functionality oneself. I decide to still rely on the declarative `desc` elements and we can trivially use these even with rendering tooltips ourselves.

In the following SVG document, a tooltip definition is used as a template, and whenever the "mouse" pointer (anything that can generate "mouse*" events, really) enters an element, we extract the document fragment (`Range`) that is the contents of its `desc` element and copy these contents into the "contents" group/graphics of the tooltip. On top of that, we calculate the position where the tooltip should be shown -- at the tip of the mouse pointer -- and we resize the background "panel" so that it actually resembles what most people accept as tooltips.

You can add your own styling and even animation to further refine desired result.

More explanation is in the comments in the code below:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style>
        #rich-tooltip {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        #rich-tooltip .panel {
            fill: silver;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <!-- the actual template, will be removed from the context and always shown as appended at the end of the document body, so that it is rendered above everything else. -->
        <g id="rich-tooltip">
            <rect class="panel" /><!-- just some decorative background -->
            <g class="contents" /><!-- contents of an element's description will be added as child nodes of this element -->
        </g>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="yellow">
        <desc><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" /><text dominant-baseline="hanging" fill="red">First circle</text></desc>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="70" cy="50" r="40" fill="green">
        <desc><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" /><text dominant-baseline="hanging" fill="red">Second circle</text></desc>
    </circle>
    <script>
        const tooltip = document.getElementById("rich-tooltip");
        tooltip.remove(); /// Initial state of the tooltip is "not shown" (removed from DOM tree)
        var timeout; /// We only show the tooltip once the pointer settles and some time passes
        const tooltip_delay = 1000; /// Delay before showing the tooltip once pointer settles
        var last_tooltip_ev; /// Auxilary variable to be able to calculate movement after showing the tooltip, so we don't remove it immediately but only once the pointer actually moved substantially, this is just a nice touch, not otherwise crucial
        const remove_tooltip_move_threshold = 10; /// How many user units (pixels, normall) the cursor may move before tooltip is hidden
        function on_mouse_move_event(ev) {
            if(document.contains(tooltip)) { /// Is the tooltip being shown?
                if(last_tooltip_ev) {
                    if(((x, y) => Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y))(ev.clientX - last_tooltip_ev.clientX, ev.clientY - last_tooltip_ev.clientY) >= remove_tooltip_move_threshold) { /// has the pointer moved far enough from where the tooltip was originally shown?
                        tooltip.remove(); /// Hide the tooltip
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(show_tooltip, tooltip_delay, ev);
            }
        }
        function show_tooltip(ev) {
            const desc = ev.target.querySelector(":scope > desc");
            if(!desc) { /// Does the element that is under the pointer even have a description?
                tooltip.remove(); /// Hide the tooltip (ignoring the fact it may not be showing in the first place)
                return;
            }
            document.documentElement.appendChild(tooltip);
            const desc_range = document.createRange();
            desc_range.selectNodeContents(desc); /// Select all children of the description element, as `desc_range`
            const contents = tooltip.querySelector(".contents");
            const contents_range = document.createRange();
            contents_range.selectNodeContents(contents); /// Select all children of the tooltip contents element, as `contents_range`
            contents_range.extractContents(); /// Empty tooltip contents
            contents.appendChild(desc_range.cloneContents()); /// Fill contents with previously selected description. We _copy_ the description -- the original should legitimately stay where it was
            const panel = tooltip.querySelector("rect.panel");
            panel.setAttribute("width", contents.getBBox().width);
            panel.setAttribute("height", contents.getBBox().height); /// "Stretch" the panel so that it covers the tooltip contents
            const pt = document.documentElement.createSVGPoint();
            pt.x = ev.clientX;
            pt.y = ev.clientY;
            const view_pt = pt.matrixTransform(document.documentElement.getScreenCTM().inverse()); /// We need to convert mouse pointer coordinates to the SVG viewbox coordinates
            tooltip.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${view_pt.x} ${view_pt.y})`); /// Move the tooltip to appropriate position
            last_tooltip_ev = ev; /// Save the event to be able to calculate distance later (above)
        }
        addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev) { /// When the pointer gets over an element...
            ev.target.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mouse_move_event); /// We will be tracking pointer movements to trigger timeout for showing the tooltip
            ev.target.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { /// Once the pointer gets anywhere but the element itself -- like over its children or other elements...
                ev.target.removeEventListener("mouseout", on_mouse_move_event); /// Cancel the whole mousemove business, the behavior will be setup by whatever element the mouse pointer gets over next anyway
            }, { once: true }); /// Once, for this element, everything else will be setup by another call for "mouseover" listener
        });
    </script>
</svg>
```

The code would be simpler without timeout triggering etc, but chances are a well thought out and user friendly tooltip implementation would be using delays and compensate for stray pointer movements, so I thought I'd make sense to keep some skeletal framework in place for these and also demonstrate how one would go about implementing them.

This is anyway fairly optimal in the sense that you only use one set of listeners at each time -- you don't need to assign listeners to each and all elements you want to track. If an element has a description, this script will make sure a tooltip is shown, is all. Temporarily, we do assign `mouseout` listener to an element but it's typically only one listener assigned to only one element at any point in time -- as soon as the pointer gets out of an element, the listener is removed (and something else reassigns another instance of it, but that's perfectly fine).

Comment: Dear @amn I have to admit your solution is too advanced for me. So let's say I want to use title option. I menage to generate title tag for each circle.                
var title = svg.selectAll("g.gradici circle").append("title"). How I can get text for titles from Array of data (city names separated by ,) to fit corresponding title element. Option is not to write title text by hand because I have a lot of circles. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to never use JavaScript as source of data if you can avoid it -- that's what your document is for -- `title` elements should go *inside* your circles. JavaScript is for *using* these data, not for generating them. You *have* to write text by hand anyway -- either you are doing it in the script (which is usually but not always the wrong place for it) or in the markup. It's not like your titles are going to be magically generated, is it?

Comment: No magic unfortunately :) All my svg files are generated from CorelDraw, so any data I have is stored in my svg as class, id or some kind of attribute. So tooltip text for each circles should be class values of each circle. And when I hover over circle his tooltip is showen/hidden. This is what I'am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't think tooltip text should `class` values -- the `class` attribute denotes a class, and has little to do with any kind of textual description. Maybe you mean that you want to correlate `class` (and values of attributes like `id` etc) values with some text? For example, if you have one or multiple `<circle class="gradicii">...</circle>` you want a certain text as a tooltip for these, text that is specific for circles with that class?

Comment: No, actually circle1 has class="first", circle2 class="second", circle3 class="third"...and so on...so I need to generate data from class values (first, second, third...) and use them for tooltip text. So, when I hover over circle1 the tooltip show first, when I hover over circle2 tooltip show second....

Comment: Alright, if you want to do it quick and dirty, map classes that are encountered in the SVG file CorelDraw exports, to tooltip text you want to show. Showing tooltips can be done using the code in the answer or by merely attaching a `title` or `desc` or `metadata` elements to each `circle` through some XML processing, using XSLT or just with JavaScript. I'll write up an answer which will replace both of my answers and cover all use-cases, hopefully that will suffice :)